# JQuery selector does not work in dynamically created content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the .html() .val() or something else within a html element, this is my html code (generated dynamically):

```
<div class="presupuesto"><h2 class="precio" id="precio" value="1202">1.202,00 €</h2>
```

> I need the .val() attribute!

With JQuery and JavaScript I want to show, what option from a select has been selected and then show the information about h2 tag (price). This is my JS code:

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {

    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    alert(valueSelected);
    alert(("#precio").val());

});
```

> The first alert(valueSelected) works well, but the second one triggers a TypeError

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add all relevant code in OP

Comment: And copy/pasted, not as images

Comment: Also, `div` elements don't have a `val` attribute. Use `data-val="1202"` and then `$('#precio').data('val')` to retrieve it

Comment: sorry! just edited

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that works! i did not know about data-val! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you have dynamically generated elements. Then You need to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):-

```
$(document).on('change','select',function(){
  alert($(this).val()); // to get select value
  alert($('#precio').attr('value')); // try to use data-attribute which is standered way
});
```

***Note:-*** Since `<h1>,<h2>..,<div>,<ul><li><p>....` these elements don't have `value` attribute (In standered way). So use `data-attribute` option for them like below:-

```
<h2 class="precio" id="precio" data-value="1202">1.202,00 €</h2>
```

And then change jQuery code just a bit like below:-

```
 alert($('#precio').data('value'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue! the problem was not in event-delegation, it was in the attributes declaration! Thank again for your feeback

Comment: Yeah! I have to wait a few minutes to accept! Already done :)